# Plotting regions and adding color in leaflet R

Tags: r, leaflet

I need to plot a map of Denmark divided into regions (there are 5: Region Nordjylland, Midtjylland, Sydjylland, Sjælland and Hovedstaden) and then color the regions such that the different regions stand out clearly. I have to use leaflet, since it has other features, that I will use later. I found a map on naturalearthdata.com, that I think I can use, but I can't figure out how to color (or even indicate) the regions. The code I tried is below

```
library(rgdal)
library(leaflet)

download.file(file.path('http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http/',
                        'www.naturalearthdata.com/download/50m/cultural',
                        'ne_50m_admin_1_states_provinces_lakes.zip'), 
              f <- tempfile())
unzip(f, exdir=tempdir())

world <- readOGR(tempdir(), 'ne_50m_admin_1_states_provinces_lakes', encoding='UTF-8')
DK <- subset(world, name=="Denmark")
leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% addTopoJSON(DK, weight = 1, color = "#444444", fill = TRUE)
```

How does one use the naturalearthdata.com data to plot regions/states/provinces of different countries? I have seen a very nice example at
http://www.56n.dk/kort/dk2050kort_age.html
but there is no sample code available.

I have also found a very nice example here: https://rpubs.com/walkerke/leaflet_choropleth - but I need a map of Denmark.

#### UPDATE: I have found a shapefile at http://www.kortforsyningen.dk which does the trick. So now my question is how do I combine my own data with a shapefile and plot it in leaflet? If I just put

```
DK <- readOGR(".../shape", layer="REGION")
leaflet(data=DK)
```

I get a blank screen...